# Xubuntu install stopped booting today ( video drivers related )

Tags: kernel, xubuntu, amd-graphics, opengl

So today ( literally one hour ago ) I tried turning my PC on after not having used it for a few hours. Once I did that I got stuck at the (just an example no my actual message):

```
dev/sda1: clean, 552599/6111232 files, 7119295/24414464 blocks
```

So after waiting for LOOONG time and trying rebooting several times, I started searching for a troubleshooting help that ended up leading to try to run this :

```
glxinfo | grep Mesa
```

And this command threw :

```
Error: Cannot open display
```

So that lead me to purging and reinstalling my AMD GPU drivers, but the process fails every time. This is the error I am getting:

```
Setting up amdgpu-lib32 (20.20-1098277) ...
Setting up amdgpu (20.20-1098277) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel
```

And now as soon as I run glxinfo I get:

```
glxinfo | grep Mesa
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.5
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.0.5
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 20.0.5
```

But my resolution is only 1024x768 and it looks awful.

Why are the drivers having trouble to effectively install?

My Linux version and Kernel :

```
[~]@somewhere #> uname -a
Linux somewhere 5.13.0-28-generic #31~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 19 14:08:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[~]@somewhere #> cat /etc/*rele*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: Since you can still access the GUI, try installing the drivers with the additional drivers tool in software sources.

Comment: it says there is no additional drivers to install.